# SQL Server Mirror: Witness Server(s)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

Inherited a new SQL estate that has never been touched by a full time DBA. Mirroring has been setup and removed on multiple servers but not fully, old witness servers are still active.

Is there anyway from the witness server to determine if a principle/mirror is still communicating or active.

I have picked through the DMV's with the DMV below being the most helpful but one of the four witness instances does report a connection, any advice would be helpful.

**sys.dm_db_mirrroing_connections**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly understand the need, but i guess below might help:

To get the information between Principal and mirror via witness query the dmv [sys.database_mirroring_witnesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/database-mirroring-witness-catalog-views-sys-database-mirroring-witnesses?view=sql-server-2017)

You can get the info from columns

*`principal_server_name`* -- Name of partner server whose copy of the database is currently the principal database

*`mirror_server_name`*  --Name of the partner server whose copy of the database is currently the mirror database.

Also, check out the cool commands from dbatools [Get-DbaDbMirror](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaDbMirror)

```
PS C:\> Get-DbaDbMirror -SqlInstance  sql2016
```

Gets properties of database mirrors and mirror witnesses on sql2016 SQL Server instance

Comment: Thanks mate.  I know its an odd question but there are bits of mirroring still active on various servers but no one seems to know what if any are still live.  One SQL server has 4 instances but only 6GB of RAM ( I know ) I want to shut the unused instances that were previously used for witnesses.  I am sure nothing uses them but just paranoia.